# Change runtime version azure functions with powershell

Tags: function, azure, powershell, runtime

Can the "latest" version of runtime from Azure Functions be changed to version "1", using PowerShell? I can not find any script that allows to do it in an automated way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the runtime verion, essentially change the `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` to `~1` in the **Application settings** of your function app.

Try the command below, it works fine on my side.

**Note**: The command will override all your Application settings, so you need to include the `$AppSettings` with all your other settings like the sample.

**Sample**:

```
$AppSettings = @{
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION" = "~1"
    "setting1" = "111"
    "setting2" = "222"
}
Set-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -Name <FunctionAppName> -AppSettings $AppSettings
```

[image]

**Check in the portal**:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Joy. But in this way I would have to go one by one, changing it. What I want is a script that runs through all the Function and change only those that have the runtime version in "latest" version to "version 1". It's posible?...

Comment: Seems impossible currently.

Comment: Anyway, your answer solves my problem, in large part. Thank you very much.